# Вставить элемент после элемента

Tags: jquery

Сейчас вставляться в элемент xfield_holder_address, а как вставить после?

```js
var total = 0;
function add_new_image(){
   total++;
   $('<div>')
   .attr('id','xfield_holder_address_'+total)
   .addClass('form-group')
   .append (
       $('<div>')
       .append('<label class="control-label col-sm-2">Адрес #'+total+' </label>')
       .addClass('col-sm-10')
       .append(
           $('<input type="text" /></div>')
           .addClass('form-control width-500')
           .attr('id','xf_address'+total)
           .attr('name','xf_address'+total)
       )                               
                               
    )
     .appendTo('#xfield_holder_address');                 
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    add_new_image();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xfield_holder_address" class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Адрес #1: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control width-500" name="xfield[address]" id="xf_address" value=""><input type="button" value="Добавить еще адрес" id="add" onclick="return add_new_image();"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

Comment: пробовал не работает

Comment: Вам нужен `insertAfter`

Comment: да точно, все ок спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var total = 0;
function add_new_image(){
   if (total == 10)
     throw new Error("Already 10.");
     
   total++;
   $('<div>')
   .attr('id','xfield_holder_address_'+total)
   .addClass('form-group')
   .append (
       $('<div>')
       .append('<label class="control-label col-sm-2">Адрес #'+total+' </label>')
       .addClass('col-sm-10')
       .append(
           $('<input type="text" /></div>')
           .addClass('form-control width-500')
           .attr('id','xf_address'+total)
           .attr('name','xf_address'+total)
       )                               
                               
    )
     .insertAfter('[id^=xfield_holder_address]:last');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    add_new_image();
});
```

```css
#xfield_holder_address {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xfield_holder_address" class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Адрес #1: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control width-500" name="xfield[address]" id="xf_address" value=""><input type="button" value="Добавить еще адрес" id="add" onclick="return add_new_image();"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88650/discussion-on-answer-by-igor----).